# Function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, call

I'm stumped, I can't seem to get this simple Javascript function to get called.
Thanks!

```
 <html>
 <head>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function increase()
    {
        alert(" the button was pressed");
    }

</script>         
 </head>

 <body>


 <form action="Test.html" method="post">

   <input type="submit" onclick="increase();" />

</form>   

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Well, you're not calling it anywhere we can see. That would explain the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell where you are going wrong. It looks like you are just defining a function. This will case the increase function to run when the page is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function increase() {
    alert(" the button was pressed");
  }
  increase();
</script>
```

This will run the function when a button is pressed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function increase() {
    alert(" the button was pressed");
  }
</script>
<button onclick="increase()">text</button>
```

It sounds like you are just getting started, and that is awesome. I would also suggest getting a book. A few years ago, I read [DOM Scripting](http://domscripting.com/book/) by Jeremy Keith, it was okay. Also, try looking around online for tutorials.

Comment: does the button have to be in a Form tag?
if so, how should it look,
Thanks

Comment: Nope - doesn't have to be a part of a form.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" id="buttonId">Button</input>

<script language="javascript">
    function increase() { alert(" the button was pressed"); } 

    document.getElementById("buttonId").onClick=increase;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? You need to place JavaScript between script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase() { alert(" the button was pressed"); } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Praveen said, wich I agree, there are good beginner tutorials [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Essential_Javascript_--_A_Javascript_Tutorial) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: you're welcome. Read this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664/is-reputation-important

Answer (score 0):

in your code the form submits as you click the button.
what you will have to do is return false; so that the form doesnt submit..

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return false; increase();">
</form>
```